# Calculating a sum per unique row from a data set with dynamic values

Tags: google-sheets

So I have a Spreadsheet with Game Statistics and I wanna display a pie chart with win percentages in general and per game.

I've created my main data table like so

```
Date     | Game   | Player 1 | Player 2
---------|--------|----------|----------
01.01.17 | Game 1 |        1 |        0
02.01.17 | Game 2 |        0 |        1
03.01.17 | Game 2 |      0.5 |      0.5
```

Now calculating the sum of wins per player is easy. But generating it per game is not that straight forward.
Right now I have a second table where the calculations are happening with a Table which looks like this:

```
Game   | Player 1 | Player 2
-------|----------|----------
Game 1 |        1 |        0
Game 2 |      0.5 |      1.5
```

I'm using an `UNIQUE` for the list of games and a `DSUM` for each cell.
This has two problems.

1. I need to copy the `DSUM` Statement each time a new Game is added (the Sheet is only for two players so I don't need to cover the case when a new Player is added)
2. When there are two different games which share a part of the name (like "Phase 10" and "Phase 10 Brettspiel" the wins of the second game do count to the wins of the first game

My Statement looks like this

```
DSUM(Data!B1:D100, E1, {"Game";D2})
```

where `Data` contains the first table, `Game` is the column with the unique games and `E1` contains the player name.

The first Problem is actually not that severe but I would like to fix the second Problem. I'm not really experienced with Google Sheets which is why I wanna solve this in pure Sheets commands and not with a custom script.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm reading the second problem right. Do you want "Phase 10" and "Phase 10 Brettspiel" to be counted together or not?

Comment: I do not want them to be counted together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `unique` and `dsum`, I suggest using [`query`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en) which can do both things at once. It eliminates the need to copy-paste any formulas, as a single `query` performs all the calculations. For example, if your data is in A:D, the query could be

```
=query(B:D, "select B, sum(C), sum(D) where B <> '' group by B order by B asc", 1)
```

which means:

- add up the contents of C and D for each distinct entry in B
- ignore the rows where B is empty
- sort the results by B alphabetically
- the range B:D has 1 header row (specified by the last argument, so it's not mistaken for data)

If other headers for the result are preferred, use "label" as follows:

```
=query(B:D, "select B, sum(C), sum(D) where B <> '' group by B order by B asc label sum(C) 'Player 1', sum(D) 'Player 2'", 1)
```